# JS: What do the curly braces inside function parameter declarations mean?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, babeljs

I have been following [this tutorial](http://www.robinwieruch.de/the-soundcloud-client-in-react-redux/) on setting up React with Redux, and I noticed some syntax that I am not familiar with. What are the curly braces inside the function parameter definition doing?

Example:

```js
function Stream({ tracks = [], onAuth }) { #what is going on here?
  return (
    <div>
      ... #component stuff here
    </div>
  );
}
```

Is this React specific? Or does this have something to do with Babel or some other library? I am new to this tech, so not sure what is going on.

Comment: The function is being passed an object literal as a parameter.

Comment: What does that mean? That the function, when called, will need to have an object literal? How does one pass something to a function like this?

Comment: It looks like destructuring syntax, but I didn't know javascript had destructuring. If that's what it is, the function is expecting an object with a `tracks` field (but can default to an empty list of the object doesn't Hebert one), and a `onAuth` field, which must be supplied. It's basically a neater way of accessing the passed object's fields.

Comment: @Carcigenicate that is exactly what it is: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: If you put that as an answer I will mark it as correct. I had no idea what this was even trying to do until you mentioned it.

Comment: Thanks. This must be new in ES7.

Comment: @derigible Wow lol. I don't know how I missed that for 5 months :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like destructuring syntax, but I didn't know javascript had destructuring.

If that's what it is, the function is expecting an object with a `tracks` field (but can default to an empty list if the object doesn't have one), and an `onAuth` field, which will default to `undefined`. It's basically a neater way of accessing the fields of the passed object.